# saving switch position and load data in another view controller

Tags: load, save, uiswitch, autosave

I am building an app witch automatically generates an email with different chosen options by the user of the app. I have 3 view controllers each with 10 / 15 different options. The user has the possibility to choose different options by sliding an Switches on/off. 
This switch changes an Label into "chosen option A" or "not chosen option A" when selected off. When i change from viewcontroller while testing, the switches all go to the standard off position when i am going back to the viewcontroller. The chosen position is not stored in the app. This means that the text in Labels also go to the wrong text (not chosen option)

First question: How can i store the switch position so the text always stays like the user has chosen? This without a separate safe button and how do i automatically reload these settings while opening this view controller?

Then, is it possible to generate the text from these labels into one TextField or TextViewer on a separate viewcontroller? for example i named this page "email" the user then has the possibility to look at the text in the text box (textfield or text viewer) and has the possibility to add any command to these texts.

I have already created an email function that generates an email from my app including receiver, subject and message body.

Please make your answers as easy/clear as possible because i am really new in programming ios app's. I prefer some example codes to use.

Thanks for the answer(s) and sorry for my bad English.

With kind Regards,

Tim